# `RouteAware`-implementer unsubscribe from any previous dependency?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

The following snippet is from the Flutter docs of `RouteObserver`:

```
   @override
   void didChangeDependencies() {
     super.didChangeDependencies();
     routeObserver.subscribe(this, ModalRoute.of(context));
   }

   @override
   void dispose() {
     routeObserver.unsubscribe(this);
     super.dispose();
   }
```

I don't understand why `didChangeDependencies` does not include `routeObserver.unsubscribe(this)` as well.

Shouldn't the `RouteAware`-implementer unsubscribe from any previous dependency?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is safe because the implementation of `subscribe` does nothing if `this` is already on the subscribers list.

Comment: But what happens if the `ModalRoute` is a different one now?

Comment: It doesn't matter. There's nothing to unsubscribe if `ModalRoute` changed.

Comment: Why is subscribe not called from initState then?

Comment: That's simply not possible. `ModalRoute.of` can't be called inside `initState`.